# Use BitBucket pipeline to build a maven project on pull request merge

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

So I am using AWS Codepipeline and BitBucket as a repository.
AWS CodePipeline does not have support for BitBucket as a source.So I have configured my source to be AWS S3.I manually run AWS CodeBuild which creates a war file of my maven project,and moves the zip file to S3.Once the S3 source changes,CodePipeline triggers automatically.

The issue with this approach is I have to manually trigger CodeBuild when my branch is merged to develop branch.I want to automate this process too.
As of now AWS CodePipeline does not support Pull request merge event.

I was thinking If I could use BitBucket pipeline to build a maven project on pull request merge and deploy the war file to S3,and from there AWS CodePipeline can pick it up.

So do BitBucket support trigger based on pull request event, if yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull Request builds for PR_Merge is supported in CodeBuild now. Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-bitbucket-pull-request.html#sample-bitbucket-pull-request-filter-webhook-events.

Comment: What should be the server url of codeBuild in order to configure webhook at BitBucket end?

Comment: Are you not using CodeBuild's console UI or CloudFormation stack to create the webhook as part of your CodeBuild Project? Webhooks are associated 1:1 with with the CodeBuild project today. You can set up the webhook by setting the webhook flag in your project when creating or updating.